# Heuristic function vs cost

Tags: artificial-intelligence

What is the difference between heuristic function and cost ? I'm too much confused between these two terms. Can someone please voluntarily explain this with any example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function ranks the alternatives, the cost is the cost of the operation.

Comment: ranks the alternatives in which sense ?

Comment: Imagine a search algorithm. The heuristic functon contains the 'logic' to determine the costs of the different paths, and by ranking these paths, it returns the cheapest path.

Comment: as far as i get this is like heuristic function will determine the cost to calculate the cheapest path towards goal. Is this what you're trying to say ?

Comment: And during that determination, the 'subproblem costs' for different paths are compared by the function. The cheapest path is the outcome with the lowest overall costs found by the logic of the function.